# Python recursive function for a sequence

Tags: python, recursion, sequence

How can I find the nth number in sequence: nth = a*q^(n-1).

So far I have done this:

```
    def func(n,a1,q):
        if n == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return func(a1 * q^(n-1))
```

I am getting error for 2 missing required positional arguments a1 and q. The result should return the nth number of the sequence a1 * q^(n-1) when I call it, "func(3,4,2)" would be 16 in this case.

Comment: You don't seem to have enough parameter in the recursive call. Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You are *defining* `func` to be a function of 3 variables, but `a1 * q^(n-1)` is just a single value, and you are trying to pass that single value to `func`.  Perhaps you intended `func(a1, q, n-1)`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Seems like a clear case of a homework assignment stipulation.

Comment: I know thats the case but somehow I need to return the nth number and I don't know what to type in the else statement to return that nth number

Comment: Did you understand the point of my first comment? 3 and 1 are different numbers. Your function takes 3 inputs. `a1 * q^(n-1)` is just 1 input. It is irrelevant that you, as someone looking at that in the code, can identify that this expression involves 3 ingredients.

Comment: Thats the thing I understand that part, but something in the else statement to return the nth number and I don't know how...So like it can't be the way I showed as that is missing arguments

Comment: You need to put the arguments in the correct order `func(n-1,a1,q)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first term of this function is n1 = a*q^(n-1) = a*q^(1-1) = a*q^0 = a*1 = a. This is the break condition for the recursion. The code for that is

```
    if n == 1:
        return a     # You returned 1 here
```

The second term is n2 = a*q^(n-1) = a*q^(2-1) = a*q^1 = **a*q**.

The third term is n3 = a*q^(n-1) = a*q^(3-1) = a*q^2 = **a*q*q**.

The fourth term is n4 = a*q^(n-1) = a*q^(4-1) = a*q^3 = **a*q*q*q**.

So what the recursion needs to do is: multiply by *q* each time. The code for that is:

```
return q * func(...)
```

Whole function:

```
def func(n, a, q):
    if n == 1:
        return a
    return q * func(n-1, a, q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a solution to your question.

```
def func(n,a1,q):
    if n == 1:
        return a1
    else:
        return q * func(n-1, a1, q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are looking for a recursive solution, unless it is some sort of homework assignment (in which case, use the other answers).

There is a direct way to express your "nth number in the sequence":

```py
def func(n, a, q):
    return a * q**(n-1)
```

And, if you are looking for the whole sequence (up to a given value of `n`), then:

```py
import numpy as np

def funcall(n, a, q):
    return a * q**np.arange(n)
```

Example:

```py
>>> funcall(10, 4, 2)
array([   4,    8,   16,   32,   64,  128,  256,  512, 1024, 2048])
```